# Is it possible to update Lambda function with .jar uploaded to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, limit

I'm trying to update Lambda code with .jar file uploaded to S3.

Direct zip file upload works fine

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name function 
--zip-file fileb://function.zip
```

Direct jar file upload works fine

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name function 
--zip-file fileb://function.jar
```

Update with zip file from S3 works fine

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name function --s3-bucket bucket 
--s3-key function.zip
```

Problem appears only when updating function with jar from S3

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name function --s3-bucket bucket 
--s3-key function.jar
```

Apparently AWS Lambda tries to unpack the jar:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

I couldn't find any clue in `update-function-code` reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

Is it possible to update Lambda function with jar file from S3?

If no, is there any reference saying so?

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the [250MB upload limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), that's all I can say from the error message.

**Solution:** Work on your application, or ask support to raise the limit.

Lambda size can be 250 MB (unzipped, including layers) for s3 uploads.

Direct uploads is 50MB (compressed), but this goes little higher to ~70MB & it uses based64 encoding.

You don't see errors on directly uploading for compressed (zip/jar) file <70MB.

If you don't want jar files to be extracted, you must zip it. Zip will be extracted!

Could probably tell more if you update with size of zip, jar, dependencies and presence of layers.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's not answering my question. Nevertheless if I upload a jar that unpacked is less than 250MB, Lambda will unpack it, but then I'll get the error saying that the handler class was not found. Different error but problem remains the same.

Comment: Lambda needs a handler, add path to handler in the function configuration tab in Lambda. It's beside Runtime dropdown selector.